# Is it ok to offer cash to a colleague to do a task that I do not want to do?

Tags: ethics, task-management

I was given this task that hardly anyone wants to do and is so boring. It is also on a boundary of my expertise. The DB gives some general recommendations when I tell him politely that I am stuck with it. Hiring a contractor is not an option.

I am so frustrated about it that I would happily pay cash to another guy who is good at it, but assigned to more urgent stuff at the moment. At the same time I feel that it may be looked at as something inappropriate. Although I do not see which policy it may violate (gift policy? But it is not a gift. What do you think?

Comment: Is it ok?  No.  Have you raised your issues with your manager?

Comment: If the task is boring and nobody wants to do it, can it be automated?

Comment: It is already automated in a way but does not work and it is working out why and going through it that makes it boring. Also i am not an expert in this area and not interested in it.

Comment: "Although I do not see which policy it may violate" - Offering a colleague anything (money or otherwise) in order to circumvent your manager's directions is the problematic part.

Comment: Isn't it allready a problem itself if some one else fixes stuff, where your suiperior asigned YOU to solve it?

Comment: Wow, I want to work in a company where you can actually have a conversation with your DB ^_^ Sounds a lot easier than writing SQL queries.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit SQL queries might get you better responses than general recommendations. "Please find records older than five years old." -> "Have you tried looking in the purchase order table?  That's where I'd expect to find them."

Comment: When I get a boring task, I look at it as an opportunity to ask "How can I automate my way out of ever doing this again?".  Once a solution is automated, the on-going cost is reduced, which is good for the business, and building the solution was fun.  It's a win-win, once you put yourself in the right frame of mind.

Comment: @Brandon - I think this is what is meant by the (alleged) Bill Gates quote: 'I choose a lazy person to do a hard job. Because a lazy person will find an easy way to do it.' Plus once it's automated, you have more time for SE.

Comment: Just put an audio book in headphones and do it. Drag it out even. Every few months we have to hand solder 500-800 chips into circuit boards. It is below everyone's pay-grade. Anyone CAN do it, they are pin-thru chips. No one wants to do them. I've jumped at it so much, I get to do them by default.  Maybe I've been Tom Sawyered?

Comment: No. He's already getting paid, and being paid to be your colleague too. Sets a dangerous precedent. Why shouldn't he ask you for money every time you want him to do something from now on?

Comment: Correction: DB means Dear Boss and not database in this context:)

Comment: @JayRandom You should edit the question.  The "DB" is being understood as "Database Administrator".

Comment: It is entirely possible that someone at StackOverflow can actually fix your problem if you're stuck, instead of worrying about the legality of paying off your colleague...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I agree with Viv's answer, but I think it is worth expressing why it is inappropriate.

If you offered money, and your colleague accepted, one of two things would happen. He would do it as part of his work, or in addition.

If he did it as part of his work, you would have paid him to change his priorities from those set by management, a conflict of interest.

If he did it in addition, you would be hiring him as a contractor, without getting permission to pay a contractor and doing all the proper tax and similar paperwork.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it, though I do not think one can hire an existing employee as a contractor. But the other thing- gift policy in financial organisations at least- says one cannot accept any amount of cash, even minimal.

Comment: @JayRandom That is one of the reasons why it would be inappropriate, even if he did the work outside normal working hours.

Comment: "I do not think one can hire an existing employee as a contractor." Certainly you can. This is called [*moonlighting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlighting). (And as Patricia notes, it would be illegal if done without the correct paperwork etc., and even if you did do the paperwork, it would be unprofessional.)

Comment: It's also worth noting the "on the boundary of my expertise" line.  It's a feature of good management for people to get on-the-job training with things they can't currently do.  It also helps avoid "information silos" where only one person can do a job.  Trying to skip out on that could cause a problem for your manager.  The "boring" part is tricky, because often there are boring things which still have to happen for work to get done.  And I'm not sure how something can be "boring" whilst involving learning some new stuff.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: *moonlighting* is an employee working for **some other party** under contract outside the hours of their normal job.  I agree with Jay's statement that working **for the same company** under both consulting contract and as employee is generally not possible.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't think there is anything specific about who you'd work for in moonlighting. (I'd be surprised if "moonlighing" were a legal term with a precise meaning.) In this case, the colleague A would anyway not be working *for the company*, but *for one colleague B of his*, since B would be employing A *as a private individual* - A happening to do work B should be doing for the employer of both A and B. Lawyers would likely have a field day with this, but I'd not bet on it being straightaway illegal.

Answer (score 14):

It is definitely not OK to offer cash. If you think the other person is suitable for the task, perhaps you can arrange to swap tasks with them, through your manager or whoever assigned the task to you. If all else fails, perhaps the other person would agree to helping you out or offer some guidance with the task?

Answer (score 1):

It would only be acceptable in a situation where your boss said: "Jay and Jim, I have two tasks here and each task needs to be done by one of you. You figure out between yourselves who does what". And then you would negotiate who does what.

Comment: And you think in that case it would be acceptable if Jay bribes Jim into taking the more uncomfortable task? I'm not that much into this, but THIS sounds for me like having even more potential to backfire.

Comment: @Zaibis -paying someone to work is literally the opposite of bribe.

Comment: In this case, paying cash  seems no worse than two colleagues bartering like "Hey Jim, I know you're better at X and can do it in half the time as me, if you do this task for me,  I'll buy beers next time we go out" (a transaction that I've witnessed more than once, and have even participated in myself). Or sometimes it's bartering tasks to work on: "Jim, if you write X for me, then I'll run the marketing reports for the next month"